# Can I have 1 pipeline and dynamically target multiple environments?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Is it possible to have 1 pipeline and dynamically pass stages to the pipeline rather than predefining the stages in the pipeline? I am trying to get out of copying pipelines over and over for different stages.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get out of copying pipelines over and over for different stages.

You could use the [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) in the YAML file in the stages instead of copying pipelines over and over for different stages:

```
stages:
- stage: QA
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - template: ChildForTemplate.yml
      parameters:
        param1: $(Var1)


- stage: Test
  jobs:
  - job:
  - template: ChildForTemplate.yml
    parameters:
     param2: $(Var2)
```

But this method still requires you to predefine the stages in the pipeline.

> Is it possible to have 1 pipeline and dynamically pass stages to the
>   pipeline rather than predefining the stages in the pipeline?

We do not currently support this feature.

If we want to completely dynamically pass stages to the pipeline, we need set YAML like:

```
stages:
- stage: $(StageValue)
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - template: ChildForTemplate.yml
      parameters:
        param1: $(Var1)
```

However, there are no specific rules for the value of the target `$ (StageValue)`, it could be only `QA`, or `QA` and `Test`, If we pass multiple values, then Yaml will not tactfully start different stages to execute the pipeline.

Hope this helps.